# How to show a hidden form?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile

I am wondering how do you re show a hidden windows form(in this case a windows mobile form but probably done the same way in windows forms).

Like Say I do this

Load Form 1
Click on a Button to Load Form 2 up
Click on a button to load Form 3 up and hide Form 2.
Click on a button to close Form 3 up and show Form 2.

I know how to hide and show them it is just hide() and show().

this is I am not sure how to call the Form2.show().

```
Form3 Form = new Form3()
Form.show();
this.close();
```

So this would make it show Form 2 would be closed then if I wanted to recreate it

```
Form2 Form = new Form2()
Form.show()
this.close()
```

So if I would do the above code then I would have 2 Form2 shown since I would have 2 Form2 objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating new forms every time before showing them, try to create them once and save the reference to that Form (as a member in your class, for example). Then use that reference to show the form.

Comment: So what have a static property that holds the Form object?

Comment: Nothing has it by default, but you can add it wherever it's appropriate (depending on the design of your application). You can even add a static Form2 member inside Form2...